# Boto3 Create Stack with existing Resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, boto3

i would like to replicate the behaviour of creating a new stack by using existing resources using boto3.

replicating the behaviour we can see on this blog post:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-new-stack.html

Comment: Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you would like to create a CloudFormation stack that points to existing resources.

To do this, you would need to **write the CloudFormation template** that matches the existing resources, and then "import" those existing resources into the stack. **It will *not* write the template for you.** It is simply a way of avoiding resources being created again.

If you want to have something write the template for you based on existing resources, I would recommend using [Former2](https://former2.com/), which can scan your account for existing resources and write a matching CloudFormation template.

Comment: No, boto3 cannot 'write' a CloudFormation template based on existing resources.